# Play authenticate create roles and signup page for different roles

Tags: playframework-2.5, play-authenticate

Please am using Play authenticate play framework and am trying to create many roles and how to create different signup and login form for each role i created.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create different signup for every role. Role is assign to user after the user get created. Assigning of role should be handle by admin and super user. So I would suggest you initially don't assign any role or give the lowest priority role. And then make the user ask the admin for a particular role.

But if you really want to assign user a role during sign up you can add a dropdown field in your form which contains the values of all the roles and assign the role while creating the user.

I hope this answer your question.